# Silverlight - Screen blank after attaching Grids to a Canvas for printing

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

So, in order to print my Silverlight grids I had to Children.Remove them from LayoutRoot and Children.Add them to my Canvas I am using for printing. (Since they can only be attached to one parent element at a time).

Which is fine, but then this leaves my screen blank, as the Grids have been removed from LayoutRoot.

So I tried Children.Remove from the Canvas and Children.Add back to LayoutRoot, but it doesn't add anything back onto the screen.

How should I deal with this? Thanks.

(Using Silverlght 5 and VB.net).

My code:

```
If PageCounter = 1 Then
        Dim PrintSurface As New Canvas
        Dim topPosition1 As Double = e.PageMargins.Top + 10
        Dim topPosition2 As Double = e.PageMargins.Top + 600
        CompChartGrid.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, topPosition1)
        AttChartGrid.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, topPosition2)
        LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(CompChartGrid)
        PrintSurface.Children.Add(CompChartGrid)
        LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(AttChartGrid)
        PrintSurface.Children.Add(AttChartGrid)
        e.PageVisual = PrintSurface
        PrintSurface.Children.Remove(CompChartGrid)
        PrintSurface.Children.Remove(AttChartGrid)
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(CompChartGrid)
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(AttChartGrid)
        PageCounter += 1
        e.HasMorePages = True
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to clipping.
When you set the Canvas.Top property on your elements, this value will persist until replaced. So when you add CompChartGrid and AttChartGrid back to the LayoutRoot grid, they are offset by topPosition1 and topPosition2 respectively.

Try calling

```
CompChartGrid.ClearValue(Canvas.TopProperty)
```

and

```
AttChartGrid.ClearValue(Canvas.TopProperty)
```

The elements should then end up back where they started.

Comment: And maybe calling LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout() after adding back all the child elements?